# Kendo scheduler grouping by week in month view

Tags: kendo-ui, grouping, scheduler

How can I group the days in month view into weeks number?

Something like this:

[image]
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't supported by the Kendo UI Scheduler. Currently not possible.

Comment: hi atanas, thanks for the feedback. I end up writing custom elements and calculations outside the scheduler to at least attain this view.